# Написать скрипт, который запускает макрос в PowerPoint. Макрос запускает презентацию на выполнение

Tags: windows, vbscript, powerpoint, wsh

Необходимо написать скрипт, который запускает макрос в PowerPoint. Макрос запускает презентацию на выполнение. Необходимо использовать Windows Script Shell, перерыл кучу всего в гугле, но так ничего и не нашел. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Как ни странно, но навскидку готовое решение "нагуглить" в явном виде сложно. Возможно, проблема в том, что возникает путаница в терминах VBscript и VBA.
Однако ответ довольно легко выстраивается, если знать, как работает автоматизация приложений на примере MS Word. Примеров полно в англоязычной части **SO**.

Чтобы не забыть, в форме памятки выложу здесь пример.

```
Dim msApp,msDoc

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 MsFile = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\Presentation1.pptm"

  Set msApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application") 
  msApp.Visible = true
  Set msDoc =  msApp.Presentations.Open(MsFile)

  msApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("Module1").Activate
  msApp.Run "Macros1"
  msApp.Quit 

 Set msDoc = Nothing 
 Set msApp = Nothing 
 Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Просто возникла проблема именно в создании макроса для запуска слайд-шоу. Ибо как я понял, нужно сначала открыть PP, Создать макрос, сохранить, закрыть PP и запустить скрипт, который будет открывать PP и, собственно, запускать макрос

Comment: Если нужно **создать** макрос средствами WSH, то это уже совсем другой вопрос, в отличие от того, как **запустить** макрос. Однако принципиальной разницы между вопросами не вижу, и примеры решения 1-го вопроса легко "гуглятся".

Comment: Если нужно просто **запустить** презентацию, то для этого **не надо** создавать макрос. Достаточно вызвать нужный метод у требуемого объекта: [**msApp.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slideshowsettings.run). Отсюда советую Вам точнее ставить вопрос, что нужно сделать. А уже потом определять средства решения задачи. Достаточно было понять, как автоматизируется процесс управления приложением MS Office, а затем понять к какому свойству, либо методу управляемого объекта нужно обратиться, чтобы достичь цели. Все ответы - в Сети.